# Is there a way to dynamically generate nodes from JSON with apoc.load.json procedure?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to create a set of nodes and relationships from a JSON document. Here is sample JSON:

```
{"records": [{
    "type": "bundle",
    "id": "bundle--1",
    "objects": [
        {
            "type": "evaluation",
            "id": "evaluation--12345",
            "name": "Eval 1",
            "goals": [
                "test"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "subject",
            "id": "subject--67890",
            "name": "Eval 2",
            "goals": [
                "execute"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "relationship",
            "id": "relationship--45678",
            "relationship_type": "participated-in",
            "source_ref": "subject--67890",
            "target_ref": "evaluation--12345"
        }
    }]
}
```

And I would like that JSON to be represented in Neo similar to the following:

```
(:evaluation {properties})<-[:RELATIONSHIP]-(:subject {properties})
```

Ultimately I would like to have a model that represents the evaluation, subject, and relationship generated via a few cypher calls with as little outside manipulation as possible. Is it possible to use the apoc.create.* set of calls to create the necessary nodes and relationships from this JSON? I have tried something similar to the following to get this JSON to load and I can get it to create nodes of an arbitrary, in this case "object", type.

```
WITH "file:///C:/path/to/my/sample.json" AS json
CALL apoc.load.json(json, "$.records") YIELD value
UNWIND value.objects as object
MERGE (o:object {id: object.id, type: object.type, name: object.name})
RETURN count(*)
```

I have tried changing the JSONPath expression to filter different record types but it is difficult to run a Goessner path like `$.records..objects[?(@.type  = 'subject')]` thanks to the embedded quotes. This would also lead to multiple runs (I have 15 or so different types) against the real JSON, which could be very time consuming. The [LoadJSON docs](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-json-rest-api/) have a simple filter expression and there is a [blog post](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/) that shows how to parse stackoverflow but the JSON objects are keyed in a way that is easy to map in cypher. Is there a [cypher trick](https://gist.github.com/jexp/caeb53acfe8a649fecade4417fb8876a#creating-nodes-and-relationships-dynamically) or APOC I should be aware of that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Are there always 3 items in the `objects` array and are they always in the same order (evaluation, subject, relationship)?

Comment: No and no. The object array can have a variable number of records and order is not enforced. There can be multiple relationships too.

Comment: And there can be multiple records?

Comment: No. A Single records array, objects are variable.

Comment: But that single records array can have multiple record items, correct? Also: are there only those 3 `type`s, are there many different `relationship_type` values, and do `source_ref` and `target_ref` imply a directionality for the equivalent neo4j relationship?

Comment: At least 15 different `types` and the relationship type value are generic but do have directionality `source -> target`. I have updated the question with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lju pointed out, the `apoc.do.case` function can be used to create a set of conditions to check, followed by a cypher statement. Combining that with another apoc call requires the returns from each apoc call to be handled properly. My answer ended up looking like the following:

```
WITH "file:///C:/path/to/my/sample.json" AS json
CALL apoc.load.json(json, "$.records") YIELD value as records
UNWIND records.objects as object
CALL apoc.do.case(
    [object.type="evaluation", "MERGE (:Evaluation {id: object.id}) ON CREATE SET Evaluation.id = object.id, Evaluation.prop1 = object.prop1",
    object.type="subject", "MERGE (:Subject {id: object.id}) ON CREATE SET Subject.id = object.id, Subject.prop1 = object.prop1",
    ....]
"<default case cypher query goes here>", {object:object}
)
YIELD value RETURN count(*)
```

Notice there are two apoc calls that `YIELD`. Use aliases to help the parser differentiate between objects. The [documentation](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/cypher-execution/running-cypher/) for the `apoc.do.case` is a little sparse but describes the syntax for the statement. It looks like there are other ways to accomplish this task but with smaller JSON files, and a handful of cases, this works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as a two-pass method:

First pass: create the nodes for evaluation and subject. You could use [apoc.do.case/when](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/cypher-execution/running-cypher/) if helpful

Second pass: only scan for relationship and then do a MATCH to find the `evaluation` and `subject` nodes based on the `source_ref` and `target_ref`, and then MERGE or CREATE the relationship to connect them.

Like this you're not impacted by situations such as the relationship coming before the nodes it connects etc. or how many items you've got within `objects`

Comment: How will this allow me to define the node type dynamically? On the first pass apoc.do.case/when will allow me to create a case statement with a case for each known node type?

Comment: You can do something like...

`UNWIND value.objects as object
CALL apoc.do.case([object.type="evaluation", "MERGE (:Evaluation {<the properties})", object.type="subject", 
"MERGE (:Subject {<the properties>})], "", {object:object}) 
YIELD value

RETURN COUNT(*)`

Comment: Thank you for this tip Lju. I was able to combine the apoc.do.case and apoc.load.json calls together to get something working. I will add an answer a little later with everything put together.